# cannot start clickhouse-client due to DB::Exception: Array data type family must have exactly one argument

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

One of the nodes in our clickhouse cluster is not accepting queries. Sending any query to the box returns this error:

```
<server>:~# /usr/bin/clickhouse client
ClickHouse client version 21.12.3.32 (official build).
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Connected to ClickHouse server version 21.12.3 revision 54452.

<server> :) Cannot load data for command line suggestions: Code: 42. DB::Exception: 
Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Array data type family must have exactly 
one argument - type of elements. (NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS_DOESNT_MATCH) (version 
21.12.3.32 (official build))
```

Does clickhouse client run a query at startup and it has somehow gotten corrupted? I am full stumped. Have tried reinstalling the client, no help. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: clickhouse-client queries database objects during startup for suggestions (tab-complition). It can be disabled by `-A` argument. `clickhouse-client -A`

Comment: Thank you! Adding the flag works. Is there a way to see this query somewhere? It would help identify which object is causing the problem.

Comment: tail /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log

Comment: `select * from system.query_log where exception <> '' and event_date >=today() limit 100`